# conditional rendering List with flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a model of 'contracts' and one of the parameters is if the contract is active/inactive. I did this condition using a bool true/false in the contractModel file.
Now, I am rendering a ListView.Builder with all the contracts, but I have created a filter at the top of the screen to select the contracts that are active/inactive. What I want to achieve is to render the active contracts in the 'active' ListView.Builder and the inactive contracts in the 'inactive' ListView.Builder.

This is the code for the ListView.Builder:

```
  return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Categories(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: contracts.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ContractCard(
                contract: contracts[index],
                press: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                      contract: contracts[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reference package([flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_conditional_rendering)), explanation from the author ([medium post](https://crizantlai.medium.com/flutter-conditional-rendering-the-right-way-fead813a3558)).This is how you would normally conditionally render widgets

```dart
return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        someCondition == true ?
          Text('The condition is true!'):
          Text('The condition is false!'),
      ],
    );
```

with the above package though you would instead do

```
return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Conditional.single(
          context: context,
          conditionBuilder: (BuildContext context) => someCondition == true,
          widgetBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Text('The condition is true!'),
          fallbackBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Text('The condition is false!'),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.